# run oracle query inside the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

Dears

I have a script which has a oracle SQL query that export data from table then store in a file.

The problem is when I execute it manually, it's working properly but when I set it to crontab it shows me a empty file as output.

what should I do to fix this?

please consider below details:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd mypath

rm -f previousfile
cat /dev/null >newfile 

info=/mypath/newfile 

/bin/sqlplus -S credentials  << EOF >> $info

set echo off
set heading off
set feedback off
set termout off
set trimout on
set colsep ","
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 10000
set trimspool on

set markup csv on
spool newfile 

select * from mytable;

EOF

cat column.csv >final.csv
cat newfile  >>final.csv
```

Comment: can you run the script with bash -x in your crontab to see the output ?

Comment: Do you see a log from crontab? It doesn't look like you're setting up your environment within that script; when you run it manually you're presumably either running oraenv or setting environment variables (`$ORACLE_HOME` etc.) in your .bashrc or similar. That won't happen via cron, unless you explicitly do it from your script.